# Bug in Pattern.asPredicate?

Tags: java, regex, java-8

Given following list of Strings:

```java
List<String> progLangs = Arrays.asList("c#", "java", "python", "scala");
```

and a regex Pattern that should match 4-letter lowercase string.

```java
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[a-z]{4}");
```

Now I want to find elements of `progLangs` that fit to the Pattern `p`.

Doing it the old way:

```java
for (String lang : progLangs) {
    if (p.matcher(lang).matches()) {
        System.out.println(lang);
    }
}
```

I get the expected result:

```
java
```

But when I try to achieve the same with Java 8 stream and transform the pattern to a predicate using [Pattern.asPredicate](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#asPredicate--):

```
progLangs.stream()
    .filter(p.asPredicate())
    .forEach(System.out::println);
```

the result is:

```
java
python
scala
```

Why is it so? It seems that Patter.asPredicate produces a predicate that accepts partial matches. What is the equivalent in the Pattern API? The [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#asPredicate--) says only:

> Creates a predicate which can be used to match a string.

I would expect it to be the typical `Pattern.matcher(String).matches()` but it's something else... How to explain this inconsistency?

Comment: With JDK/11, [`matches` is available](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51791652/1746118) as well and your initial code does what you intended it to, just with a method call change. :)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

They are not doing the same thing - the Predicate uses [`find` rather than `matches`](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/lambda/lambda/jdk/file/2b0c2fc213d6/src/share/classes/java/util/regex/Pattern.java#l5746). The equivalent 'old code' way would be:

```
for (String lang : progLangs) {
    if (p.matcher(lang).find()) {
        System.out.println(lang);
    }
}
```

In this case I would use my own predicate:

```
progLangs.stream()
    .filter(s -> p.matcher(s).matches())
    .forEach(System.out::println);
```

The documentation does seem misleading though.

Comment: It looks like you're right. However, I still can't understand why they implemented it this way. Is really the usage of Matcher.find() more common than Matcher.matches()?

Comment: I couldn't say, perhaps I'm missing something.

Comment: @LukaszWiktor actually choosing `find` or `match` is not that important because we can write regex which can make `find` act like `matches` by adding surrounding it with `^` and `$` like in your case `^[a-z]{4}$`, or make `matches` act like `find` (invoked once) by surrounding regex with `.*` like `.*serchedPattern.*`. Maybe `find` has been chosen because it is faster, since it will stop iterating after finding first matching substirng instead of iterating over entire string like in case of `.*regex.*`.

Comment: Very good point from LukaszWiktor. You should edit the answer to make sure that it is brought to people's attention.

Comment: Made another answer, now that, [`matches` is available](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51791652/1746118) as well.

Answer (score 7):

With [JDK/11](http://jdk.java.net/11/), you can use the new **`Pattern.asMatchPredicate`** API to accomplish what you were initially trying to, in a one-liner as :

```
progLangs.stream()
         .filter(p.asMatchPredicate()) // the matches predicate
         .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Here is what the javadoc for the same reads :

```
/**
 * Creates a predicate that tests if this pattern matches a given input string.
 *
 * @apiNote
 * This method creates a predicate that behaves as if it creates a matcher
 * from the input sequence and then calls matches, for example a
 * predicate of the form:
 *   s -> matcher(s).matches();
 *
 * @return  The predicate which can be used for matching an input string
 *          against this pattern.
 * @since   11
 * @see     Matcher#matches
 */
public Predicate<String> asMatchPredicate() {
    return s -> matcher(s).matches();
}
```