# Different response for Pattern.matcher and Predicate.test

Tags: java, regex

What is the explanation for this code?

```
   String key = "camera.cameraConfiguration.2a";
   // This regex just allows "extensions", anything after the \d+ block, to the usual format
   String regex = "camera.cameraConfiguration\\.\\d+(\\..*)?";
   Predicate<String> predicate = Pattern.compile(regex).asPredicate();

   // This one used predicate --> Return true BUT it should be FALSE because the regex says: give me only   number then an optional string formatted like ".thenAnyCharYouWant"
   System.out.println(predicate.test(key));
   // Return false
   System.out.println(key.matches(regex));
   // Return false
   System.out.println(Pattern.compile(regex).matcher(key).matches());
```

Why the Predicate.test seems to give the wrong answer?

Answer (score 6):

According to this answer [Bug in Pattern.asPredicate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23540817/bug-in-pattern-aspredicate)

Predicate does check for strings using the "contains" way. Use the relevant Pattern.asMatchPredicate if you are using JDK11+. Otherwise do your own predicate function or use commons-lang3 library.

If you are experiencing the strange behaviour that is not desired, you can always see the implementation of the java core libraries. See this [link](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u/jdk/file/c46daef6edb5/src/share/classes/java/util/regex/Pattern.java) for this particular problem.

Comment: I think it is worth noting that the "contains" way is similar to a one-off `pat.matcher(str).find()`, if someone coming across this page is looking to "use the relevant method" for the "contains" sense.